# Create a string from multiple values

Tags: ansible

How do I create a "string" from values in a dictionary?
I have the following host_vars:

```
host_info:
    fqdn.hostname.a: 
        listen_ip: 12.34.56.78
        name: service-a
        domain: a.my.domain.com

    fqdn.hostname.b: 
        listen_ip: 23.45.67.89
        name: service-b
        domain: b.my.domain.com
```

in my target config file I have the following:

### TrustedHosts

```
127.0.0.1
funkyDomain.com
{{trusted_hosts}}
```

How can I get the `listen_ip` directive to "assemble" into `trusted_hosts` so that the output looks like below:

```
127.0.0.1
funkyDomain.com
12.34.56.78
23.45.67.89
```

I've looked around at building arrays but I don't think this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to combine the 2 dictionaries first.

```
host_info:
  fqdn.hostname.a:
    listen_ip: 12.34.56.78
    name: service-a
    domain: a.my.domain.com
  fqdn.hostname.b:
    listen_ip: 23.45.67.89
    name: service-b
    domain: b.my.domain.com
```

Then you can loop over the combined dictionary in a jinja template for your target config file (it looks like you already started one).

```
127.0.0.1
funkyDomain.com
{% for value in host_info.values() %}
{{ value.listen_ip }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I already had them grouped, in my case in another group name (fixed the question). Do I need the key part on the loop?